# How to restrict the choice of a user in python?

Tags: python, input, integer, user-input, string-length

So I have this program where I need the user to choose a length for a key in python but I want the choice of the user to be restricted with the provided lengths only and I don't quite know how to do that here is the code

```
available_len = [5 , 10 , 14 , 12 , 15, 16 , 18 , 20 , 21]
length = int(input("[+]:Select the length you want for your key: "))
```

I want to make so that if the user inputs a length not available in the list to print "Please choose a valid length" and take him back to input the length

I have tried:

```
 while True:
        length = int(input("[+]:Select the length you want for your key: "))
        if 5 <= length <= 21:
            break
```

Comment: check the result from input.  if it is not among choices, raise an exception.

Comment: Well, do you know how to repeat code? Do you know how to print the message? Do you know how to check whether the `length` is in the list? What exactly is preventing you from putting these pieces together? If you don't know one or more of those things, they're easy to look up, and have been answered many times before. (Or you could try following a tutorial). Otherwise, you [need a more specific question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), which starts with trying to write the code.

Comment: How do I make it so it compares them like use and if-else statement or like use % or something like that

Comment: You want to know whether the `length` is in the `available_len` or not, right? Did you try putting "in python, how do I check whether a value is in a list?" into a search engine? Or anything remotely like that?

Comment: Sounds like a great job for the [walrus](https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/).

Comment: yeah it came with different solutions that I don't want

Comment: Sorry, but in the real world, you have to make an effort to look for solutions; you have to think about the results that you find; and [when all else fails](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), you need to make a clear effort to communicate about why and how you are still stuck.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have tried something if this is what is bothering you I will apply to the code

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it's okay man you are free to do whatever I was just trying to fix something that got you mad

Comment: I am not angry, or otherwise emotional in the slightest. I am only trying to explain how the site works. I gave you multiple helpful links already.

Comment: Yes I did not assume that you were not helpful and I did see the reason for your downvote so I fixed the mistake I made by not showing what I have done so yeah that's it really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control what the user inputs. You *can* control whether or not you ask for a different input.

Model this with an infinite loop and an explicit `break` statement.

```
available_len = [5 , 10 , 14 , 12 , 15, 16 , 18 , 20 , 21]
while True:
    length = int(input("[+]:Select the length you want for your key: "))
    if length in availble_len:
        break
```

While you can shorten this using an assignment expression, I find this approach to be clearer.

```
available_len = [5 , 10 , 14 , 12 , 15, 16 , 18 , 20 , 21]
while (length := int(input("[+]:Select the length you want for your key: "))) not in available_len:
    pass
```

You could replace `pass` with a `print` statement explaining why the previous choice was invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
available_len = [5 , 10 , 14 , 12 , 15, 16 , 18 , 20 , 21]
length = -1
while length not in available_len:
    length = int(input("[+]:Select the length you want for your key: "))
```

Output:

```
[+]:Select the length you want for your key: 7
[+]:Select the length you want for your key: 30
[+]:Select the length you want for your key: 14
```

Comment: This works too thank you

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop until a wanted answer is received:

```
available_len = [5 , 10 , 14 , 12 , 15, 16 , 18 , 20 , 21]
length = -1
while length not in available_len:
    length = int(input("[+]:Select the length you want for your key: "))
    if length not in available_len:
        print("Length not accepted, try again")
print(length)
```